# Can unconstructive users be suspended on chat?

Tags: discussion, chat

Recently I happened to be on a chat where the users were busy talking crap (marriages, wifes, etc). I mean how at all can they even chat crap when they are supposed to chat something constructive? The group name is technology related and the chat is way off the books.
Is there any way (algorithms etc.) which automatically/manually suspend users from talking nonsense on chat?

Comment: Which chat room? Which messages?

Comment: Messages like is any1 married , r we supposed to have 4 wifes etc.

Comment: @Stijn Check the Android group http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15/android for more info

Comment: So is the problem that you think the entire chat should be about Android, or is it that you are offended by the subject they're discussing? My gut tells me it's the latter.

Comment: the latter offcourse if they wanted to discuss it they can discuss anything on any social networkin site why here

Comment: `-1` because it's unconstructive and unproductive to begin a conversation about solving a problem by stating that what other people are talking about is "crap". Oh, the irony.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you look at the description of the chat room, it says

> Tales of the fight between green robots and nyan cats, in the realm of Unicornia. We can teach you to fish, but we're not giving out free tuna. Read the House Rules! spifftastic.net/room.15

This makes it clear that this particular chat room is for the lighter side of Android. When you look at the linked page, you will find (among others) the following rules:

> 5 . Everything unicorn-related is allowed.
>   6 . Please don’t post unprofessional images. Kitties and unicorns: okay. A screenshot of your app: sure. Twerking: no.

So, this chatroom allows lighthearted talk, and things that are not necessarily about Android, provided it remains safe for the workplace.

You'll have to find a chat room where the rules are more strict, or create one yourself.

That being said, an algorithm to determine if a chat is on-topic could be tricky. I'd much prefer human moderation. 
(Disclaimer: I rarely use chat myself, so I don't know what methods chat has available for community-moderation).